# Programmatically create a scrollview with 2 columns of buttons Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, android-linearlayout

I have a scrollview created that I add a variable amount of buttons to programmatically, but I now have to make it so that I have a second smaller button beside each of the buttons within the scrollview. Here is my screen now:
[image: ![Here is my scrollview now]

I would like there to be a small button beside each of those that would let me delete the option or something along those lines.

Here is my code I have now to build the buttons

```
    public void addButtons() {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.loadLinearLayout);

        int i = 0;
        for(File file : files) {
            Button newButton = new Button(this);
            String filename = file.getName();
            newButton.setId(i);
            newButton.setText(filename);
            newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    loadGame(view.getId());
                }
            });
            i++;

            linearLayout.addView(newButton);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a `GridView` or a `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a `Button` for each file, add a whole `LinearLayout` for each of them, with horizontal orientation. Then, add to this inner linear layout first the button with the file name, then the delete button (they will appear in a row).

```
public void addButtons() {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.loadLinearLayout);

    int i = 0;
    for(File file : files) {
        //create horizontal linear layout
        LinearLayout innerLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        innerLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        Button newButton = new Button(this); //button which shows file name
        String filename = file.getName();
        newButton.setId(i);
        newButton.setText(filename);
        newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loadGame(view.getId());
            }
        });
        innerLayout.addView(newButton);

        Button deleteButton = new Button(this);
        deleteButton.setText("Delete"); //use a string resource ideally
        innerLayout.addView(deleteButton);

        linearLayout.addView(innerLayout); //add the inner layout to the outer
        i++;
    }
}
```

You might need to do some additional styling, such as set the distance between the buttons, or align them in a way. You should also be able to do that programmatically somehow, but that is a different story.

Comment: That worked for me thank you so much! I need to find a way to ensure that the second button doesn't get pushed off screen by the first button, but I haven't been able to figure out how to put the constraints required for that, but once I figure that out it will be perfect.

Comment: @JadonLatta You can try to set the max width of the button and play around with "ellipse" property, this cuts the text with ... if it gets too long. Not sure if this property can be changed programmatically.